# How to get the name of the calling alias method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0, ruby-2.1

I am having method called `link_to_admin` then I have aliased another method called `simple_link_to`

```
def link_to_admin(name,url,options={})

  # My stuff here
  link_to(name,url,options)          
end

alias_method :simple_link_to, :link_to_admin
```

Here I am facing one problem if I call `link_to_admin`, I want print the value into `<li>` tag

Ex.

```
def link_to_admin(name,url,options={})

  # My stuff here
   menu = ""
   menu << "<li> #{link_to(name,url,options)}</li>"
   menu.html_safe
end
```

And if I call `simple_link_to` no need of `<li>` tag. So currently I am passing one `options` like `li_required` then am checking condition in my method. This is working perfectly, I know this is correct way to do it.

```
def link_to_admin(name,url,options={})
   menu = ""
   menu << options[:li_required] ? "<li> #{link_to(name,url,options)}</li>" : link_to(name,url,options)
   menu.html_safe
end
```

But,Before I was trying to find the calling method like `simple_method` or `link_to_admin`, so I tried with:

```
1.__method__
2.caller[0]=~/`(.*?)'/
```

This is not working as expected.

I am calling `simple_method` or `link_to_admin` methods in `layout` so `__method__` is always returning `link_to_admin` only.

But `caller[0]=~/`(.*?)'/`if am calling from`layout`means, it's returning layout path and if I am calling from any other`helper`or`class` means it's returning current method.

Any other way is there to check method name.

I know this is not good question, could any one please tell me any other way.

Note:- I have created alias_method for naming conversion only. Other than adding `<li>` tag I am not doing any thing.

Not only here am having this doubt from long back. I know I can define one more method and I can do it.

Leave my scenario, generally I wants to know this answer.

Comment: Why did you use alias_method? delegation won't work?

Comment: Here why we need `delegate`?

Comment: I did not mean `delegate` the keyword, but the idea - simply call one method from the other method (as @pdobb suggests)

Comment: Thanks for your reply,leave my scenario,Generally i wanted to know this answer.

Answer (score 24):

Using `__callee__` instead of `__method__` will get the name of the alias being run.

Comment: Thank you for proving the answer to the actual question.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend that, instead of relying on method names and branching (which will become brittle with any method name refactoring, is obviously more complex, etc.) that you simply break apart the methods more to abstract common logic into a shared method.

Here's how I would write it:

```
def simple_link_to(name, url, options = {})
  # shared_link_to(name) ... or whatever
  link_to(name, url, options)
end

def link_to_admin(name, url, options = {})
  # shared_link_to(name) ... or whatever
  content_tag(:li) do
    simple_link_to(name, url, options)
  end
end

private
def shared_link_to(name)
  # do whatever is common
end
```

Note: I've made a bit of a guess that you have common code that you'd want to abstract out into some method (which I've called `shared_link_to`)... but do what you need with that part.

Comment: other than adding `li` am not doing anything.

Comment: Not only here,from long back am having this doubt.