# How to get the name of the calling alias method in a Module?

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby method which is aliased to several alternative names, and within the method, I would like to know which alias has called me.

[This posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23806577/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-calling-alias-method) suggests that I could use `__callee__` to get at this information. However, this does not work in my case, since I am in a module and the method is a module method. The following example demonstrates the problem:

```
module Demo
  extend self
  def f
    puts __callee__
  end
  alias g f
  alias_method :h,:f
end

Demo.f
Demo.g
Demo.h
```

This outputs

```
f
f
f
```

and not

```
f
g
h
```

Could someone explain, why it doesn't work, and how I can do it correctly?

UPDATE: From the feedback I got here and also from other developers, this seems to be a bug in Ruby, which was fixed in 2.3.4.

Comment: Works for me (ruby 2.3.4)

Comment: I tried it with MRI Ruby 2.3.3 for Cygwin, and with JRuby 1.7.26 (language compatible to 1.9.3), and both did not work. There must be something really odd going on; I would be surprised, if this were a long-standing bug, which just got corrected in 2.3.4. You really used copy and paste of my code to run it on your platform?

Comment: yep, [I copy/pasted](https://pastebin.com/MyM4tgFQ). Try 2.3.4 and see if it works. I'm on macos, btw.

Comment: Indeed, tried in 2.3.3 and I get `f f f`. So yes, it appears to be fixed in 2.3.4

Comment: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11964